# Error "Bad message" when accessing a file on Windows OpenSSH SFTP server

Tags: .net, windows, sftp, openssh, ssh.net

I need to transfer large files via SFTP from a web site. I cannot store these files (even temporarily) on the web server so I am streaming the file in chunks to the SFTP server.

I've installed OpenSSH ([version 5_30_2016](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases/tag/5_30_2016)) on another Windows machine and am attempting to connect to it using [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/) (version 2016.0.0).

This example code gives causes an exception to be thrown on my machine:

```csharp
const string PATH = "/D:/sftp/test.xml";
var Client = new SftpClient("host", 22, "username", "password");

Client.Connect();   

if(!Client.Exists(PATH))
{                       
    var s = Client.Create(PATH, 1024 * 4);
    s.Dispose();        
}   

var Data = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\Temp\TestFile.xml");  
using(var w = Client.Open(PATH, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.ReadWrite)) // this line throws an exception
{
    w.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length);
}

Client.Disconnect();
```

I am getting an SSH exception coming whenever I try to connect my client to append or open - basically any operation that returns a `Stream` or a `StreamWriter`.

The error I get back through the SFTP client is *"Bad Message"* which isn't very descriptive. I'm just hoping I've missed something obvious in my approach...!

I've also tried looking at using other SFTP libraries but they all seem to rely on passing a physical local file to the remote location which isn't what I want to  do. It appears that SSH.NET is the best suited to my needs as it provides methods for passing byte arrays and streams to the SFTP server

Stack trace, with message *"Bad Message"*:

```
   at Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpSession.RequestOpen(String path, Flags flags, Boolean nullOnError)
   at Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpFileStream..ctor(ISftpSession session, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync)
   at Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpFileStream..ctor(ISftpSession session, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 bufferSize)
   at Renci.SshNet.SftpClient.Open(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
```

Comment: What version of SSH.NET and OpenSSH are you using?

Comment: Do you get the same results with a plain console application? I.e. no async code. You should create [mcve] before posting a question.

Comment: Hey @MartinPrikryl I've updated my question with a simpler code snippet. In answering your question it's ruled out WebApi, the request parser and the async stuff.

Comment: Also, my first foray into SFTP and setting up SSH on windows. The WinSCP website has been a fantastic resource!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with OpenSSH on Windows and an issue was raised on Github.

https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/310

Answer (score 1):

It's the `FileMode.Append` mode.

It seems that the Windows OpenSSH server does not support it.

When you replace it with `FileMode.Create`, it works.

---

Instead of the `FileMode.Append`, you can use the `offset` argument of the `SftpFileStream.Write`.

Comment: Removing the leading slash yields the same result unfortunately. Also, the other commands that use the path with leading slash (like creating directories and empty files) appear to work regardless of the leading slash

Comment: Well, works for me. And for me even the `Client.Create` fails with the leading slash.

Comment: Anyway, can you upload the file using any command-line SFTP client, like with WinSCP: `winscp.com /command "upload sftp://username@password@host/" "put D:\Temp\TestFile.xml D:/sftp/test.xml" "exit"` + Can you even browse to the `D:/sftp` in WinSCP GUI?

Comment: I had hoped I'd be able to do that but unfortunately I can't store the file in a temp location for security reasons. The posted file must be held in memory and only materialise on the SFTP server

Comment: Well, try that from other machine with a random file.

Comment: Ran my code from another machine and it throws the same exception (Bad Message). Using winscp.com from the command line works really nicely, just wish I was able to use it without a temporary file.

Wonder whether this means it's an issue with SSH.NET..?

Comment: OK, you are right. I've updated to the latest OpenSSH for Windows and that indeed uses the leading slash. The culprit is the `Append` mode.

Comment: Thanks Martin, writing to the destination works now, just need to figure out how to offset the stream by it's current length to allow appending (getting an argument exception being thrown by the SftpFileStream). That's a little beyond the scope of this question now though. Thanks for your help